# Taking the bidual of a non-reflexive space infinity times.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

This is just a curiosity and probably not well posed question but since several other colleagues also get curious about what would be the "right" question and its answer I decided to ask it here.

Let $\Omega$ be a compact metric space and $C(\Omega)$ the space of all real continuous functions defined over $\Omega$ endowed with the supremum norm. Consider the sequence of successive biduals of $C(\Omega)$, i.e., $C(\Omega)^{**}, C(\Omega)^{****}$ and so on. Let us use the notation $C(\Omega)^{2n*}$ to denote the $n$-th element of this sequence of Banach spaces. Because of the Jordan mapping we can think that this sequence is nested, i.e.,  $C(\Omega)^{2n*}\hookrightarrow C(\Omega)^{2(n+1)*}$ so at least as sets taking limit would make some sense. The question is. Is there any reasonable sense for $\lim C(\Omega)^{2n*}$ (as being a Banach space) where one could expect $(\lim C(\Omega)^{2n*})^{**} \cong \lim C(\Omega)^{2n*}$ (reflexivity) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside the issue of how to construct the inductive limit of $\{ C(\Omega)^{2n*} \}_{n \ge 1}$, X is the limit and it is a reflexive Banach space, then the closed subspaces $C(\Omega)^{2n*}$ of X would be reflexive, which is not the case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Victor. This is a nice argument and it seems correct to me.